# React Apollo load data from cache and then make request

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Hello I have a problem with React-Apollo..

When I set the fetchPolicy to cache-and-network my Apollo makes everytime a new request and don't load the data from the cache.

I want Apollo to first load the data from the cache and then make a request and then update the data and reload the Component if the result ist different from the cache data.

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
    connectToDevTools: true,
    cache,
    link: ApolloLink.from([
        stateLink,
        new HttpLink({
            uri: "..."
        })
    ]),
});
```

```
query user($userId: String) {
    user(_id: $userId) {
        __typename
        _id
        fullname
        username
        followed_by_viewer
        follows_viewer
        edge_followed_by {
            count
        }
        edge_follow {
            count
        }
    }
}
```

```js
<Query query={GET_USER} variables={{ userId }} fetchPolicy={"cache-and-network"} partialRefetch={false} >
{({ data, loading, error, refetch }) => {

        if (error) return <Text>Error</Text>
        if (loading) return <Text>Loading</Text>

        let user = data.user;

        console.log(user);

        return (
            <ScrollView
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing={loading}
                        onRefresh={refetch}
                    />
                }>

                <View style={[s.gradientBar, { backgroundColor: profileColor }]} />

                <View style={s.nameInfos}>
                    <Text style={s.fullname}>{user.fullname}</Text>
                    <Text style={s.name}>@{user.username}</Text>
                </View>



            </ScrollView>
        )
    }}

</Query>
```

Comment: query, types ? no id prop?

Comment: @xadm now? Is that enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `_id` and `__typname` defined object should be properly cached in normalized form. You can inspect cache details/state/internals (data store) using react dev tools (to be 100% sure).

> I want Apollo to first load the data from the cache and then make a request and then update the data and reload the Component if the result ist different from the cache data.

Cache first is a default policy.

Using `refetch` (as refresh) IMHO forces network request - it's a part of existing `<Query/>` state/process, not a separate action. Cache (only) will be used (without network request) f.e. when another instance or other component requests the same data range (query, variables).

`<Query/>` component creates an observable, will refresh automatically on cache data update (f.e. after mutation from another component).